# detecting qr code then rotating document

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, qr-code, bitmapimage

Good evening all wonderful helpers,

I am trying to detect a QR code that I have on a scanned PDF(printed pdf with qr then scanned) The QR code will always be located on a corner of the file. Here in my following code I clone the area of which the QR is located.

**Help on:**
- looking over the document to see which corner has an image (qr)
- after finding the corner that has the qr code - rotate the file so that the qr code would be located on the top left corner.

**Code:**

```
for (int pg = 0; pg < inputDocument.PageCount; pg++)
            {
                QRCodeDecoder decoder = new QRCodeDecoder();
                string workGif = workingFilename.Replace(".pdf", string.Format(".{0}.gif", pg + 1));
                GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumb(workingFilename, workGif, pg + 1, 300, 300); // size (last two params) does not seem to have any effect


                using (var fullImg = new Bitmap(workGif))
                {

                    Bitmap result = fullImg;
                    //top-left
                    var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width/2, result.Height/2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //top-right
                    var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //bottom-left
                    var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //bottom-right
                    var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

//saving images for testing purpose just to see what was saved for each corner. 

                        bandImg1.Save("c:\\bandImg1.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        bandImg2.Save("c:\\bandImg2.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        bandImg3.Save("c:\\bandImg3.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        bandImg4.Save("c:\\bandImg4.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);


                    string QRinfo = Process(bandImg1);//this  should pass in the bandImg depending on the above search finding which corner has a qr image
                    MessageBox.Show(QRinfo);

                    string[] qcode = QRinfo.Split('/');
                    string gid = qcode[qcode.Count() - 1];
                    Guid pgGuid = new Guid(gid);

                    var ar = dc.Assessments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == pgGuid);
                    if (ar != null)
                    {
                        var p = inputDocument.Pages[pg];
                        string opdName = FILESTORELOCATION + pgGuid.ToString() + ".pdf";
                        PdfDocument opd = new PdfDocument(opdName);
                        opd.Pages.Add(p);
                        opd.Close();

                        ar.StoragePath = opdName;
                        ar.LastUploadedDT = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        ar.UploadedByUserID = uploadingUser;
                        dc.SubmitChanges();
                    }
                }

                //this.Refresh();
                File.Delete(workGif);
            }
```

**Process Method:**

```
public string Process(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var reader = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader();

        try
        {
            LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            return reader.decode(binBitmap).Text;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I thought the point of QR was that orientation was unimportant AND the algos could auto detect the presence of the QR code. Shirley you should just run detect on the entire pdf.

Comment: However, rotation is not needed. You should just crop the corners each out and run the QR code on them each.

Comment: @Aron - currently i am able to detect the QR code- the purpose is that this is a document that should be presented on proper format (upright reading) so if the user scanned in the document upside down i would be able to fixed it back

Comment: Does that mean you want to rotate the PDF as an output?

Comment: @Aron yes - exactly :D i've been trying to look for possible ways or even ideas but not sure where or how to start couldn't find lots of examples on this.

Comment: Slice the document in two through the middle and see which half contains the QR code.  If it's in the bottom half rotate 180 degrees.

Comment: @LorenPechtel thanks for the insight but i was actually stuck on the actual coding process - is there an example that does this - I am not sure how i could go about checking each half code wise. maybe some rough outline so i could have a clear idea. thanks

Comment: @Amina:  You've got an image.  Create two new bitmaps and copy the two halves into them.  Scan each of them.

Comment: @LorenPechtel ok thanks i will go ahead and give this a try.

Comment: @LorenPechtel one more question - as for the size of the page is there a default size or if i tell it to take half it will automatically calculate based on the actual file size?

Comment: Even though I already saw it in your other question, you should add the `Process` method here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass each `bandImg` into the process method. And depending on which one returns a valid string, you'll know the rotation you need to do.

```
//top left
var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
//top right
var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(result.Width / 2, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
//bottom left
var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(0, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
//bottom right
var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);

Bitmap[] corners = new Bitmap[] { bandImg1, bandImg2, bandImg3, bandImg4 };
string QRinfo = "";

for (int i = 0; i < corners.Length; ++i)
{
    string tmpQRinfo = Process(corners[i]);//this  should pass in the bandImg depending on the above search finding which corner has a qr image

    //check if string is valid, you'll need to figure out how to do this
    if (valid)
    {
        QRinfo = tmpQRinfo;
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: //already in upper left, do nothing
                break;
            case 1: //upper right corner, so rotate the document -90 which is the same as 270
                fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                break;
            case 2: //lower left corner, so rotate 90
                fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                break;
            case 3: //lower right corner, so rotate 180
                fullImg.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                break;
        }
        break; //the QR was found, no need to continue searching
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(QRinfo);
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I will go ahead and start applying this and hopefully it will work out great.

Comment: @Amina I added the line `break; //the QR was found, no need to continue searching` so that it will stop searching when the QR is found. No need to do extra work once it is found.

Comment: as i was doing this i got an error on build:for the forloop `for(int i = 0; i<corners.length; ++i)` with the error message being: `cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'`

Comment: @Amina I didn't get this error. Where is the error underlined? `corners` should be a `Bitmap[]` type. Also, `length` should be `Length`. It may be easier to copy/paste from my answer instead of typing it out, just to be sure it's right.