# properly using the Drawing.Rectangle with specified points c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, bitmapimage

I am trying to get an image for every corner of a scanned document ( top left and right, bottom left and right). Below is how i attempted to implement that but when i looked at the saved images they are all different parts but of the top left corner only and not the whole document. Any suggestions to how i can change this?

```
 Bitmap result = fullImg;
 //top-left
 var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
 //top-right
 var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 50, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
 //bottom-left
 var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 50, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);
 //bottom-right
 var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 375, 375), fullImg.PixelFormat);

                    bandImg1.Save("c:\\bandImg1.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    bandImg2.Save("c:\\bandImg2.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    bandImg3.Save("c:\\bandImg3.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    bandImg4.Save("c:\\bandImg4.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

**----- Updated code with additions based on answer below ------**

```
Bitmap result = fullImg;
                    //top-left
                    var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width/2, result.Height/2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //top-right
                    var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //bottom-left
                    var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);
                    //bottom-right
                    var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), fullImg.PixelFormat);

                    bandImg1.Save("c:\\bandImg1.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    bandImg2.Save("c:\\bandImg2.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    bandImg3.Save("c:\\bandImg3.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    bandImg4.Save("c:\\bandImg4.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);


                    string QRinfo = Process(bandImg1);
```

**Process Method:**

```
public string Process(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var reader = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader();

        try
        {
            LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            return reader.decode(binBitmap).Text;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the bitmaps `Width` and `Height` properties instead of hardcoded numbers.

Comment: @sparky68967 when i used the page width and height i would get an out of memory message. I want to get a certain size of each corner but are my points correct?

Comment: Well I think you're on the right track but hardcoding the points is a bad idea. You should post the code that was giving you the exception. The only way to guarantee you are getting the whole document is if you are using the width and height to calculate the corners.

Comment: @sparky68967 is there an example of what you are referring to? I am not getting an error but when i look at the images they are all for the top corner but slightly shifted.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to take the width and height of `result`, or `fullImg` into account when calculating the rectangle coordinates, instead of hardcoding values like you are. Something like this:

```
//top left
var bandImg1 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
//top right
var bandImg2 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(result.Width / 2, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
//bottom left
var bandImg3 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(0, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
//bottom right
var bandImg4 = result.Clone(new Rectangle(result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2), result.PixelFormat);
```

What you're doing now is probably not working because you are hardcoding the values. For example, for `bandImg1` you are using `(0,0,375,375)` for the rectangle which is basically saying "start at the top left, and go 375 pixels to the right, and 375 pixels down". Instead, you want to use `(0, 0, result.Width / 2, result.Height / 2)` which says "start at the top left, go halfway across the image, then go halfway down the image", which will give you the upper left corner.

Comment: Thanks this worked! i wasn't changing the x and y properly. Thanks for your help. Do you also happen to know a way in which i could search the whole document to see which corner has an image based on what i have above?

Comment: So what i am trying to do is i receive a scanned pdf that has a qr code in it. I want to find the location of the qr image (one of the four corners) so i can rotate the pdf so that the qr will be on the left top corner.

Comment: @Amina that sounds interesting. I was going to tell you to start a new question, but now I see you already have a question open for it. I'll take a look, but I don't have experience searching for an image within an image.

Comment: will i can already search for an image and pull back the qr code but my problem is that i want to have a clean way of checking which corner has an image whether in a for loop  of if else statements. Thanks for your help-i've been trying to get information but haven't been able to find a lot on this.

Comment: @Amina so with the new code in this question, are you able to determine which bandImg has the QR code?

Comment: no this is what i need to do - if i try to process each bandImg i will return an error if no qr is found. I feel like if i did nested if-else statements it would be a lot of repeating going on.

Comment: @Amina you should update your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215065/rotating-scanned-document-to-detect-qrcode, with your new code from this question. I'll look at it over there.

Comment: thanks - i really appreciate all your help. I updated the other question.